# Replacing whole website content with a wallpaper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web project where the client requires me to do that whenever the cursor hovers out of the page like when users moves the cursor to the taskbar,title bar,etc then the whole website content should be replaced with a cover screen.

I think I can use jQuery to track the mouse inside the screen. if cursor moves out of the screen, then I can set display of whole screen to none and display a cover image on whole screen. Use mouseleave(), mouseenter() functions.

But the problem is I am not that much familiar with jQuery. Help me with writing the code.

Comment: *Replace* the content, or *hide* the content by showing an image over the top of the content? Incidentally, if you're not familiar with jQuery, why not try with plain JavaScript? We'll help (happily!) but we won't do your work *for* you.

Comment: Hi...unfortunately for you SO is not a code writing service. I would suggest that a google search might be of more use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `toggleClass` on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```
$('body').toggleClass('no-mouse');
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $('body').toggleClass('no-mouse');
});
```

CSS

```
.no-mouse {
    background:red;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5zn9us9/)

**EDIT**

---

Updated the answer base on your comment,

HTML,

```
<div class="wrapper test">website content</div>
<div class="no-mouse test">without mouse image or color container.</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $('.test').toggle();
});
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background:green;
    margin:0px;    
    display: none;
}
.no-mouse {
    position :absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background:red;
}
body {
    margin:0px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5zn9us9/1/)

Comment: Thanks.But this only changes the background. What if I want to replace the whole content of the website with a color or a image?

Comment: Thank You and But one last help whenever the cursor leaves the screen and then comes back the contents are automatically scrolled up. Like if I am reading a article and I move my cursor out and then come back it automatically scrolls to the top. I want the scroll bar to remain where it was when  the cursor reenters the area.

Comment: try this sample http://jsfiddle.net/q5zn9us9/2/